# Magento2: I am getting placeholder images in cron tab. Need to get correct images in cron

Tags: magento2, crontab

I am getting placeholder images in crontab.

```
Like this:
/pub/static/version1554967977/crontab/_view/en_US/Magento_Catalog/images/product/placeholder/.jpg;
This is wrong image.
```

How to get product image in cron tab?

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$_product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($item->getProductId());
                $imageHelper  = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');
                $image_url = $imageHelper->init($_product, 'product_page_image_small')->setImageFile($_product->getFile())->resize(500, 500)->getUrl();
```

Comment: can you share the code that you are using?

Comment: Updated my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my working code:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();   
$product  = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($item->getProductId());
                            $store    = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')->getStore();
                            $imageUrl = $store->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . 'catalog/product' . $product->getImage();
```

Answer (score 1):

By using block factory you can create `List` block object, and by `List` block object you can get your image. Try code below

```
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $productModel,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\BlockFactory $blockFactory)
{
    $this->productModel = $productModel
    $this->_blockFactory = $blockFactory;
}
```

In your function, use this:

```
$imageBlock =  $this->_blockFactory->createBlock('Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct');
$product = $this->productModel->load($item->getProductId();
$imageType = 'category_page_grid';
$productImage = $imageBlock->getImage($product, $imageType);
$imageUrl = $productImage->getImageUrl();
```

Comment: $productImage = $imageBlock->getImage($product, $imageType);
$product is productid right?

Comment: no, the object of product that you have loaded

Comment: Need to get on the behalf of productids

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is working in observer. But it's not working in crontab.

Comment: Good thing is you resolved your issue. +1 for that on your answer